# Arranging data to be more readable

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am using Twitter-tools api.GetSearch to find information on Twitter.  The code works but the data it retrieves is jumbled per se.  How would I go by making the data more understandable.  For example, breaking the data down by each individual Tweet.  Right now the data looks like this..

[u'Sales at Apple stores have fallen 4.5% per square foot. The search for a new head of retail: http://t.co/YQ0LQGXfXp $AAPL', u'In rare move, Obama administration vetoes ban on sale of some Apple devices. http://t.co/UMCTcC1TQu $AAPL', u"AT&T claims it's the 1st U.S. store, even before Apple, to do away completely w/o cash registers. http://t.co/pWmTQCHlBm $T @ATT $aapl $VZ", u"Justice Department is seeking oversight over Apple's iTunes store to curb anticompetitive behavior.

What I would like is, the data broken down to each individual tweet to something like this..

[u'Sales at Apple stores have fallen 4.5% per square foot. The search for a new head of retail: http://t.co/YQ0LQGXfXp $AAPL',

u'In rare move, Obama administration vetoes ban on sale of some Apple devices. http://t.co/UMCTcC1TQu $AAPL',

u"AT&T claims it's the 1st U.S. store, even before Apple, to do away completely w/o cash registers. http://t.co/pWmTQCHlBm $T @ATT $aapl $VZ",

u"Justice Department is seeking oversight over Apple's iTunes store to curb anticompetitive behavior.

(I can do without the spaces)

Below is the code

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer key', consumer_secret='consumer secret',  access_token_key='access token', access_token_secret='access token secret')

search = api.GetSearch(term='$aapl', geocode=None, since_id=None, max_id=None, until=None,   count=15, lang=None, result_type='mixed', include_entities=None)

print [s.text for s in search]
```

Comment: What does it look like now?

Comment: It stills look the way it has…all jumbled together.

Comment: I meant more along the lines of, can you post what the output is of print[s.text for s in search].

Comment: Its in the original post but it looks like... [u'Sales at Apple stores have fallen 4.5% per square foot. The search for a new head of retail: http://t.co/YQ0LQGXfXp $AAPL', u'In rare move, Obama administration vetoes ban on sale of some Apple devices. http://t.co/UMCTcC1TQu $AAPL', u"AT&T claims it's the 1st U.S. store, even before Apple, to do away completely w/o cash registers. http://t.co/pWmTQCHlBm $T @ATT $aapl $VZ", u"Justice Department is seeking oversight over Apple's iTunes store to curb anticompetitive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer key', consumer_secret='consumer secret',  access_token_key='access token', access_token_secret='access token secret')

search = api.GetSearch(term='$aapl', geocode=None, since_id=None, max_id=None, until=None,   count=15, lang=None, result_type='mixed', include_entities=None)

#if you're not printing to the console, e.g. you're printing to a file
print [s.text+'\n' for s in search]

#otherwise use this
import pprint
pprint.pprint([s.text for s in search])
```

it looks like this for me:

```
[u'Sales at Apple stores have fallen 4.5% per square foot. The search for a new head of retail: http://t.co/YQ0LQGXfXp $AAPL',
 u'In rare move, Obama administration vetoes ban on sale of some Apple devices. http://t.co/UMCTcC1TQu $AAPL',
 u"AT&T claims it's the 1st U.S. store, even before Apple, to do away completely w/o cash registers. http://t.co/pWmTQCHlBm $T @ATT $aapl $VZ"]
```

or this also:

```
from __future__ import print_function
[print(s.text,'\n') for s in search]
```

which looks like

```
Sales at Apple stores have fallen 4.5% per square foot. The search for a new head of retail: http://t.co/YQ0LQGXfXp $AAPL

In rare move, Obama administration vetoes ban on sale of some Apple devices. http://t.co/UMCTcC1TQu $AAPL

AT&T claims it's the 1st U.S. store, even before Apple, to do away completely w/o cash registers. http://t.co/pWmTQCHlBm $T @ATT $aapl $VZ
```

to confirm; you're ok with the data, you just want it to print out differently?

Comment: Yes, i'm ok with the data, I just want it print out differently.  I;ll try this, and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, the data still prints as the original.

Comment: yeah that would only work if you're not printing to the console like if you had an actual string.print somewhere

Comment: It works!! however for the "from __future__ import print_function
[print(s.text,'\n') for s in search]" I'm getting the following error "SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file"

Comment: sorry about that, just put it as the first or second line :)